# Need PC oscilloscope for Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Can anyone recommend a PC oscilloscope that's compatible with Ubuntu? I need this for checking the waveform from an audio output.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to be more specific as to what you are trying to do. Will a program like audacity work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least these three packages in the Ubuntu repositories:

[ll-scope](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/ll-scope) - an oscilloscope [DSSI](http://dssi.sourceforge.net/) plugin

> The Oscilloscope is a DSSI plugin with a GUI that displays the audio input in an oscilloscope view. It can be useful when working with modular synths, to view the waveforms with at different places in the synth graph.

[wmscope](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/wmscope) - Graphical representation of sound waves in a dockapp

> wmscope is a dockapp that displays sound waves graphically, reading from a variety of sources. It also has a standby sine wave interference pattern to display when there is no audio input.

[xoscope](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/xoscope) - digital oscilloscope

> Xoscope is a oscilloscope using input from a sound card or EsounD and/or a ProbeScope/osziFOX and will soon support Bitscope hardware. Includes 8 signal displays, variable time scale, math, memory, measurements, and file save/load.

Comment: in your opinion which of the software among all three matches to see a wave of sound output for example on dvd player